# Cable Extension for power supply?

Tags: windows-7, power-supply

I'm looking to get another internal hard drive for my computer.  But, currently all the cables are used for the two hard drives and the optical drive. I know there is a type of cable adapter for the power supply. But, I completely forgot the name of it.

Can someone explain what I will need to split the power source and connect the additional hard drive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will likely need one of the three adapters below.  If the hard drive you are trying to add is a SATA hard drive, then you will need to get either:

**The single SATA to two SATA adapter:**

[image]

**Or, the single Molex 4-pin to two SATA adapter:**

[image]

**If your hard drives are the older IDE version then you will need to get:**

[image]

Comment: Ah Thanks a lot. I think this was what I was looking for. It seems a lot of people have been getting problems with the molex adapter frying their SSDS though... scary.

Comment: I have used several molex to SATA adapters without any problems with them frying a SSD drive.